# Problem when using special chars on Iphone app name

Tags: iphone, xcode4

I have a problem while localizing the application name. The problem appears when I put an special char on a localized CFBundleDisplayName attribute.

The default name is:

*"CFBundleDisplayName" = "seguridad";*

And the translation to portuguese:

*"CFBundleDisplayName" = "Segurança";*

With this configuration, the device always show the default name ("seguridad"). But when I replace the portuguese string with:

*"CFBundleDisplayName" = "Seguransa";*

the localized string is shown correctly.

Any help will be apreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've found the problem. Don't know why, but the file had an incorrect encoding (I've created it using xcode). Just changed file encoding and everything works fine now.

Thanks for the responses.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "the device always show" I assume you mean on the Icon?

I seem to be able to add a 'ç' to my CFBundleDisplayName just fine. As well as any other unicode characters.

I know that when you change the 'Product Name' in your Target then you have to close & reopen your project before it'll fully take effect (daft, I know). Maybe give that a try?

Comment: Yes, I mean the name above the icon. I just found the problem and posted it to help people with the same problem. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Heh, encoding would have been my next guess ;)